# Redis transaction to get overlapping values and remove values

Tags: c#, redis, transactions

I'm trying to achieve the following atomically:

1. get all values stored at redis at key,
2. check them against a parameter if there is an overlap return the overlapping values
3. otherwise update the key with the new values (keep the old values as well)
4. I also need another function that can delete values from redis
   atomically.

this is what I have right now:

```
public async Task<List<string>> AddUniqueValuesAsync(string key, IEnumerable<string> values)
{
    IDatabase db = _redis.GetDatabase();
    List<string> overlappingValues = new List<string>();

    RedisValue[] redisValues = values.Select(v => (RedisValue)v).ToArray();

    ITransaction transaction = db.CreateTransaction();
    RedisValue[] existingValues = await transaction.ListRangeAsync(key);
    IEnumerable<string> existingStrings = existingValues.Select(v => (string)v);
    IEnumerable<string> duplicateStrings = existingStrings.Intersect(values);

    if (duplicateStrings.Any())
    {
        return duplicateStrings.ToList();
    }

    await transaction.ListRightPushAsync(key, redisValues);
    await transaction.ExecuteAsync();

    return null;
}

public async Task RemoveValuesAsync(string key, IEnumerable<string> values)
{
    IDatabase db = _redis.GetDatabase();
    ITransaction transaction = db.CreateTransaction();

    RedisValue[] redisValues = values.Select(v => (RedisValue)v).ToArray();
    foreach (RedisValue value in redisValues)
    {
        await transaction.ListRemoveAsync(key, value);
    }

    await transaction.ExecuteAsync();
}
```

but my removal function is working by removing value by value and not all of them at once. and I'm not sure - how good it is if I have a lot of values? is there a better approach to this whole thing?
(I also don't want to use LUA, at least for now)

thanks!